# catch particular element from XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StudentList>
<student>
  <name>Ram</name>
  <Id>1</Id>
</student>

  <student>
  <name>Hari</name>
  <Id>2</Id>
</student>
  <student>
    <name>Gita</name>
    <Id>3</Id>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name>Sita</name>
    <Id>4</Id>
  </student>
</StudentList>
```

In page load:

```
XmlDocument XD = new XmlDocument();
        XD.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XmlFile.xml"));
        XmlNodeList nodeListName = XD.GetElementsByTagName("student");
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in nodeListName)
        {
            foreach (XmlElement xelement in xNode)
            {
                PlaceHolder pshd = new PlaceHolder();
                LblDisplay.Text += xelement.FirstChild.Value + "   ";
                string Name += xelement.FirstChild.Value;
            }
            LblDisplay.Text += "<br/>";

        }
```

i want to catch only name from the above xml file but i get name and id both.How can i do it plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XmlFile.xml")); 

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/StudentList/student");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string name= xn["name"].InnerText;
  string Id= xn["Id"].InnerText;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over `xNode` you just want its `FirstChild`:

```
foreach (XmlNode xNode in nodeListName)
{
    string name = xNode.FirstChild.InnerText;
    LblDisplay.Text += name + "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: thanks u r great i got what i want.But plz help little bit more.If i want to catch only `id` then?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LINQ to XML (in the System.Xml.Linq namespace), using XDocument:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XmlFile.xml"));

var names = from x in xDoc.Descendants("student")
            select x.Element("name");

foreach (XElement studentName in names)
{
    LblDisplay.Text += studentName.Value + " ";
}

LblDisplay.Text += "<br />";
```

If you want the id instead, you can substitute "Id" in the `select x.Element("name");` line.

Alternatively, you could grab both name and Id and return them as a collection of anonymous types:

```
var students = from x in xDoc.Descendants("student")
               select new
                   {
                       name = x.Element("name").Value,
                       id = x.Element("Id").Value
                   };
```

Which you could then access thusly:

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
    LblDisplay.Text += student.name + " student.Id + " ";
}
```

Or whatever you wanted to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath all the way:

```
nodeList = XD.SelectNodes("//student/name")
foreach (XMlNode node  in nodeList){
    LblDisplay.Text += node.Value + "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\aritra.ghosh\Desktop\Student.xml";
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(fileName);
        XmlNodeList list = xDoc.SelectNodes("StudentList/student/name");
        foreach (XmlNode item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
        }
```